# Big-O: Why is the time complexity of these loops O(N)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

I have the following function.

```
int fun(int n) 
{ 
  int count = 0; 
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) 
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        count += 1; 
  return count; 
}
```

It has `O(N)` time complexity. I thought it's `O(N LogN)`(i.e. If we remove the inner loop we get)

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2){
...
}
```

This is `O(Log N)` isn't it? And the inner loop turns out to be `O(N)` as it just increase linearly. So I think it's supposed to be `O(Log N * N)`. What might go wrong on my thought?

Comment: Mistake: The inner loop is not linear in n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how many steps the inner loop is taking. It's $n + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{4}n + \cdots$. However the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) tells us:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil\log n\rceil +c}\frac{n}{2^k} < n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 2n$$

Comment: Thanks. Not related to the correct answer. But for the outer loop, is that O(Log N) right?

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone Yes the outer loop does $\lceil \log n \rceil + c$ iterations (where $c$ is some off-by-one error I'm too lazy to figure out precisely), which is why I put it as the upper bound of the first sum.